# Animate an image like the iPhone's Email app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I want to animate an image just like the Mail app animates flying out the "envelope" icon when one tries to move an email message to a different box. I tried to use CoreAnimation, but i kind of want it to follow a curved path.

Can someone please point on how to do that?

Answer (score 7):

UIBeizerPath is the class that you can use for creating the path of the imageObject follow during the animation.

Try this animation,I have created it like image delete animation in iphone.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    UIView *senderView = (UIView*)sender;
    if (![senderView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        return;

    UIView *icon =myImageView;

    //move along the path
    UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [movePath moveToPoint:icon.center];
    [movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:senderView.center
                     controlPoint:CGPointMake(senderView.center.x, icon.center.y)];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
    moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;


    //Scale Animation
    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
    scaleAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1,0.1, 1.0)];
    scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;


    CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim, scaleAnim, nil];
    animGroup.duration = 1.0;
    [icon.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];

// create timer with time of animation to change the image.   

}
```

Remember to import the QuartzCore Framework in your project and import it in your header file.